# How to avoid RuntimeWarning for my Fourier series

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, bigdata

For a particular analytical solution of my partial differential equation, it can be expressed as a Fourier series  for which I have coded as:

```
def wire_anal(x, y, L, N):
series = 0
for n in range(1, N):
    series += (4000/((2*n)-1))*np.sin(((2*n)-1)*np.pi*x/L)*((np.sinh(((2*n)-1)*np.pi*y/L))/(np.sinh(np.pi*((2*n)-1))))
return series
```

when I run it for a particular value I want say:

```
print(wire_anal(0.25, 0, 0.5, 150))
```

I get an error of

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in sinh
```

For higher terms say:

```
print(wire_anal(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1500))
```

I get a `NaN` value instead. Is there a way round to this problem?